# Filtering is not working on C API

Tags: solace

Solace filtering is not working , able to publish but not able to consume. the selector just ignore my messages while posting. please give me the solution for that.

Comment: i am able to post messages with filters tage. those filters are added in destination header. but while subscribing it gives Zero . i am using C Apo

Answer (score 0):

When a Solace selector is used, a consuming client only receives a message if the selector evaluates to true when the message’s header field and property values are substituted for their corresponding identifiers in the selector. The Solace message broker filters out messages that do not match.

Solace selectors can only be set for consumers or browsers that are bound to a queue or a durable topic endpoint.

To publish a message that will match a selector, the selector string must be contained in the user property map, or in a specific message header field. The Destination property on a message defines where the message is published to. This will be either a topic or a queue. It cannot be used to match a selector.

For a list of message headers that can be used to match a selector, and its corresponding selector identifier string, please see the Solace Messaging API documentation page here: https://docs.solace.com/Solace-PubSub-Messaging-APIs/Developer-Guide/Using-Selectors.htm

If your consumer is not receiving the message while using a selector, please ensure that the selector string matches what is contained in the header property or user property map of the message.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i have used user C API example :https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/c/index.html. but i didnt get the proper result . it posts all the messages first and in the consumer i am using same filter what you mentioned in publisher .here i am using topic instead of Q. type also Durable if you give good example both publisher and subscriber that is good .